# simple mod_rewrite not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Im kinda new using htaccess and mod rewrite

I got every link to work as i want, but i have a problem when im trying to change the link for the forum everything goes kinda to hell..

This is my code

```
RewriteRule ^thread/([0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9]+)$ sidor/forum/showthread.php?threadID=$1&name=$2 [L]
```

When i try to get thread/1/forum it works perfectly but when i try to get a longer name like this
thread/2/cs-wont-work-for-me

The htaccess gets me a error 404..

And my links i change so (spaces) gets - and åäö gets aao

Anyone knows what the problem is?

Do you need more code? just post a comment and tell me that then i can try to give you a little more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`thread/2/cs-wont-work-for-me` is not matched because you only check for alpha numeric characters (`[A-Za-z0-9]+`). Include dashes and any other characters you want to match to your regex. This should do what you want:

```
^thread/([0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9\-ÅÄÖåäö]+)$
```

As a sidenote, I can really recommend [htaccess tester](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/) to debug issues like this.

Comment: Thank you so much alexn! That worked just as i wanted :) Thanks for the link to, now i can debug it too :)

Comment: If the solution worked, please accept the answer so the question will be marked as answered.

Comment: @Tommy Didn't see that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use as

```
RewriteRule ^thread/([0-9]+)/(.*) sidor/forum/showthread.php?threadID=$1&name=$2 [L]
```

Does not check the last sequence of string of specific pattern